# If $f$ is continuous and onto, then choose the correct statement

Tags: real-analysis

If  $f$   is continuous  and onto

Then  choose the correct statement

$a.$ $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$b$. $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, 1]$

My attempt  : I know  that a continuous image of a compact set is a compact set. As  $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact,

so I think  both  a) and b)   will not be onto.

Is  it  true?

Any hints/solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is valid to exclude (a):

If $f$ is onto, then $f([0,1])=\mathbb R$, but continuity implies that $f([0,1])$ would be compact,and $\mathbb R$  isn't.

Option (B) is possible. Just take $f(x)=|\sin x|$ or $f(x)=|\cos x|$.

EDIT: if you want a ${\cal C}^\infty$ function, just take $f(x)=\frac{1+\sin x}{2}$

Comment: You need to put absolute value on the sine and cosine functions though.

Comment: yes, of course!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your argument works for $(a)$ as $f([0,1])$ must be compact. It doesn't work for $(b)$.

for $(b)$ consider the function which is $0$ for $x<0$. It is the identity for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and it is the constant $1$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the image must be compact so it can't be option $a$. But why can't it be option $b$? Take $f(x)$=|sinx| as an example.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous, then

$U$ is compact $\Rightarrow$ $f(U)$ is compact

but

$f(U)$ is compact $\nRightarrow$ $U$ is compact

After all, if $f(x)=c$, then $f(U)$ is compact regardless of what $U$ is. And given any continuous $f$ and set $U$ such that $f(U)$ is compact, if we can find noncompact set $V$ disjoint from $U$ such that $f(V) \subset f(U)$, then $U \cup V$ is a non compact set with a compact image.

Applying this to the situation at hand, we can take $f$ to be $x \rightarrow x^2$, $U$ to be $[0,1]$, and $V$ to be $(-1,0)$. Then $W=U \cup V = (-1,1]$ is not compact, but $f(W)=[0,1]$.